# Approval workflow tables with 3NF form in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am working on one HRMS application. There is one Transfers workflow in application. As a part of it employee can get transferred from one department/office to other department/office.
**Transfers process works as below:**
Employee checks for vacancy in application and applies for transfer if vacancy is available. Once employee submits transfer form, it goes for approval to employee's department/office. There are 5 approver in approval flow. In PostgreSQL to achieve 3NF I have decided to create 3 separate tables as below:
1) One for employee's transfer request
2) Transfer request approval request
3) Transfer request approval request details
[image]

So in above image you can see for approval request I have created two separate tables i.e. **transfer_request_approval and transfer_request_approval_details**. transfer_request_approval refers transfer_request_id as FK and transfer_request_approval_details contains transfer_request_approval_id as FK and all 5 approver's record for that particular approval request.

e.g. We have transfer request with id=1, so there would be one row in transfer_request_approval table (e.g. transfer_request_approval_id = 1, transfer_request_id = 1 as FK). In transfer_request_approval_details there would be 5 rows for 5 approver's records. 
(Note: approval_status is either Approved or Reject or Rework, note is nothing but user can put some remark. If approver puts rework status it will go back to approver1 again e.g. if Approver5 put rework status it will go to approver1 again for same process. so there would be 10 records for that entire approval request in transfer_request_approval_details table).

**Question**  : Do I really need to have transfer_request_approval_details table or I can include all those approvers records in transfer_request_approval table?

Comment: What relationship does transfer_request have with transfer_request_approval. 1:1 or 1:*?

Comment: In above image, it's 1:1 mapping between transfer_request and transfer_request_approval. but as you can see above in transfer_request_approval_details table, there are be 5 approvers who approves that transfer_request (note: approver can approve/reject/rework and put some remark. In case of rework it will go to first approver1 and same process gets started). e.g. If 5 approver approves that request in transfer_request_approval_details table there would be 5 rows for each approver details. Once 5th approver approves the request in transfer_request_approval, I am going to mark status complete

Answer (score 1):

In order to maintain normal form, you need the approval details table separate, otherwise you end up with duplicate values of status for each approver. However, I see no need to have separate transfer_request and transfer_request_approval tables. Just add status to transfer_request and link to apporver_details.

Comment: Okay, got it! I think what you mentioned above make sense.

Comment: Great. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can include all those approvers records in the transfer_request_approval table.

There is no meaning in storing data in a separate 2 tables.